# Whether the operation result of the multivariate random variable of Gaussian distribution is still Gaussian distribution？

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

If it is known that $X1\in R^D$ ($D \times 1$ dimension) is a multivariate Gaussian distribution: $X1\sim \ N(\boldsymbol u1, \boldsymbol Z1)$, and $X2\in R^D$ ($D \times 1$ dimension) is also a multivariate Gaussian distribution: $X2\sim \ N(\boldsymbol u2, \boldsymbol Z2)$, where the mean vector and covariance matrix of both are known: $\boldsymbol u1, \boldsymbol Z1, \boldsymbol u2, \boldsymbol Z2$.

I would like to ask whether the random variable $X3 = X1^T * X2  (Dimension:(1\times D) \times (D \times 1) = 1 \times 1)$ is still a Gaussian distribution? and if not, can an approximate Gaussian distribution be obtained by moment matching? I know that the product of two Gaussian distribution PDFs is also Gaussian, but this operation of random variables confuses me.

If it is possible to make Gaussian approximation by moment matching, please recommend me related books, any insights from you will be greatly appreciated!